# VNC unattended on virgin instal ubuntu workstation

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc, headless

I have a new laptop running LTS ubuntu workstation. It runs the default GNOME GUI

I want to keep this thing running 24x7 and have cacti to poll several systems via script and/or SNMP. Cacti is not the problem. Also I can SSH into this laptop, no problem.

Sofar the context. Here's my question:

What I cannot get to work is it to act as a remote screen (VNC server)

That

- must spawn its own session.
- must advertise the remote vnc service
- must be able to start more than one session.
- does not require SSH tunnel.

I have tried for over a day to get x11vnc.service going, but it doesn't want to start, and I can't figure out why.
Also just now gave up on tigervnc, it is another rabbithole..

Again, a fresh ubuntu install that I only want to use for cacti. with VNC to get to my graphical interface, that's all I need.

Do any of you have a working unattended pc, or know a walk-trough of a known-good setup?

Thanks

Comment: An actual Ubuntu version number may help to assist you. By itself LTS is not a version.

Comment: Version is 22.04LTS